# Does Web Api OData Support For Generic Action?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I have an OData service based on the Web Api 4, and I wan't to add an action to this service, but the action method is generic, so is this supported?

Thanks

Comment: Are you suggesting your action isn't tied to any specific entity that is exposed by your OData service(s)?

Comment: Yes, I have a method than is for several entities.

Comment: Make base class for all controllers that use this method and inherit from it.

Comment: OK, so it's not that it's not tied to ANY entity type. It's that the same logic is tied to MORE THAN ONE entity type. Yeah, you're going to have to go with Jen's answer and expose an action on each entity type.

Answer (score 0):

No, the OData protocol does not support generics for actions or functions. You'll need to create a separate action for each type you want to support, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can publish [context-level service operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450061/wcf-data-service-where-would-i-write-business-logic/17467808#17467808) (function imports) using WCF Data Services... this requires to migrate your code from WebAPI.